# Backend Spring boot with RabbitMQ application load testing using JMeter

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, junit, jmeter, rabbitmq

I have Spring boot with RabbitMQ back-end application. I want to run my JUnit test case with JMeter for load testing. While I run Junit test case , I face below error. OmniRoute class available from other jar file. When I run Junit test case from my IDE, then it is running successfully but when I run it from JMeter then I am facing below error. I have shared my code as well.

> Error --
>   testShrotUrlGenerate(org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler$AnnotatedTestCase):
>   mb/omni/proto/OmniRoute Trace -- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   mb/omni/proto/OmniRoute   at
>   mb.omni.shorturl.handlers.ShortUrlGenerationHandlerTest.testShrotUrlGenerate(ShortUrlGenerationHandlerTest.java:79)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler$AnnotatedTestCase.runTest(JUnitSampler.java:596)
>     at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler.sample(JUnitSampler.java:396)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:627)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:551)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:490)
>     at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Error --
>   testShrotUrlGenerate(org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler$AnnotatedTestCase):
>   org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate Trace --
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate   at
>   mb.omni.shorturl.handlers.ShortUrlGenerationHandlerTest.cleanup(ShortUrlGenerationHandlerTest.java:69)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler.sample(JUnitSampler.java:400)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:627)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:551)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:490)
>     at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 11 more

I am generating jar file of project with below gradle file.

```
jar {
    enabled=true
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "MainClassName"
    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

Below is my configuration class with RabbitMQ.

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class ShortUrlGenerateConfig {

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange shortUrlExchange() {
        return new DirectExchange("exchange", true, false);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue shortUrlGenerateQueue() {
        return new Queue("queue");
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding shortUrlGenerateBinding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(shortUrlGenerateQueue()).to(shortUrlExchange()).with("routingKey");
    }

    @Bean
    public ShortUrlGenerationHandler shortUrlGenerationHandler() {
        return new ShortUrlGenerationHandler();
    }
}
```

This is my handler class.

```
public class ShortUrlGenerationHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ShortUrlGenerationHandler.class);


    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabTmp;


    /**
     * @param message
     * generate shorturl
     */
    @RabbitListener(queues = "queue")
    public void consumeMessageFromGenerateQueue(final Message<?> message) {

         String routingKey = (String) message.getHeaders().get(AmqpHeaders.RECEIVED_ROUTING_KEY);
         logger.info("ShortURL Message received on Queue["+message.getHeaders().get(AmqpHeaders.CONSUMER_QUEUE)+"], Routing Key["+routingKey+"].");
         Object correlationId = message.getHeaders().get(AmqpHeaders.CORRELATION_ID);

         Object directReplyTo = message.getHeaders().get(AmqpHeaders.REPLY_TO);
         ShortURLRequest request = null;
         ShortURLRequest.Builder response = null;

            try {
                request = ShortURLRequest.parseFrom((byte[]) message.getPayload());
                response = ShortURLRequest.newBuilder();
                if (correlationId == null || directReplyTo == null) {
                    throw new ResourceNotFoundException("CORRELATION_ID_NOT_FOUND","Invalid Correlation ID, Correlation ID not found",9103);
                }

                .
                .
                .

            }catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(" Error in consumeMessageFromGenerateQueue method.Error  is - " + e.getMessage(), e);

            }
        logger.info(" response - " + response);
        MessageProperties props = MessagePropertiesBuilder.newInstance().setCorrelationId(correlationId.toString())
                .build();
        rabTmp.send("", directReplyTo.toString(),
                MessageBuilder.withBody(response.build().toByteArray()).andProperties(props).build());
    }
}
```

Below is my Junit test case.

```
@Test
    public void testShrotUrlGenerate() throws Exception {

        OmniRoute omniRoute = OmniRoute.newBuilder()
                .setRouteType("AMQP")
                .setProcessor("processor")
                .setAmqpRoute(OmniAmqpRoute.newBuilder()
                        .setRoutingkey("routingKey")
                        .setExchange("exchange")
                        .build())
                .build();

        List<OmniRoute> omniRoutes = new ArrayList<>();
        omniRoutes.add(omniRoute);

        OmniRequest omniRequest = OmniRequest.newBuilder()
                .setRequestId("182fd990725011e9a9ca8f4121c06f8b12")
                .setRequestType("SHORT_URL")
                .addAllRoutes(omniRoutes)
                .setUserId(100)
                .build();

        ShortURL shortUrl = ShortURL.newBuilder().setOriginalUrl("http://dashboard.omni.platform/#/login").setUser(User.newBuilder()
                .setUserId(100))
                .setMessageId("3")
                .setChannel("CHANNEL_ONE")
                .build();

        ShortURLRequest shortURLRequest = ShortURLRequest.newBuilder().setRequest(omniRequest).addShortUrls(shortUrl).build();

          MessageProperties messageProperties = new MessageProperties();
          messageProperties.setCorrelationId("1f4a13d0-f3b4-4b4b-98b4-50e9d75d6032");
          Message message = new Message(shortURLRequest.toByteArray(), messageProperties);
          byte[] responseByte = (byte[])  template.convertSendAndReceive(shortUrlExchange, shortUrlGenerateRoutingKey, message);
          ShortURLRequest shortURLResponse = ShortURLRequest.parseFrom(responseByte);
          assertTrue(shortURLResponse.getShortUrlsList().get(0).getShortUrlId()>0);
          assertEquals(shortURLResponse.getShortUrlsList().get(0).getOriginalUrl(),shortUrl.getOriginalUrl());
          assertTrue(shortURLResponse.getShortUrlsList().get(0).getShortUrlCode()!= null);
          assertEquals(shortURLResponse.getShortUrlsList().get(0).getUser().getUserId(),shortUrl.getUser().getUserId());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NoClassDefFoundError: mb/omni/proto/OmniRoute

means that you don't have the .jar which contains this class in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

You can do something like:

```
task copyRuntimeLibs(type: Copy) {
    into "dependencies"
    from configurations.testRuntime - configurations.runtime
}
```

in your [Gradle build script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html) and when you invoke the task - all the .jar files which are required by your project will be copied to `dependencies` folder of your project. Once you have them - just "tell" JMeter to look for the .jars in that folder via [`search_paths` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#classpath) or just copy them to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation.

More information: [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter/)